How to consume plain text message from RabbitMQ using MassTransit in C#
I have configured the MassTransit RabbitMQ as following
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
 {
   x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
   x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
         {
             cfg.Host("localhost", hostConfigurator =>
             

{                  hostConfigurator.Username(rabbitMqConfigurations.Username);                  hostConfigurator.Password(rabbitMqConfigurations.Password);              }
);
             
             cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("testQ", configurator =>
             

{                  configurator.ConfigureConsumer<MessageConsumer>(context);                                }
);
             cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
         });
  }
 );

MessageConsumer looks like :
public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<SampleMessage>
{
  public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SampleMessage> context) 
  {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
  }
}

SampleMessage looks like :
public sealed record SampleMessage(string Data)
But when I publish message from RabbitMQ console like  'abcds'
It gives me error like this
Exception thrown: 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' in System.Text.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in MassTransit.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I used MassTransit version 8.2.4  MassTransit.RabbitMQ version 8.2.4 MassTransit.Newtonsoft 8.2.4
Please help me with this issue, any examples would be great
I tried following the below link but it did not help much
How to Consume Messages from RabbitMQ as Plain Text using MassTransit?

MassTransit does not support consuming text, it must be a type serialized in a format supported by MassTransit (such as JSON).
Supported serialization formats: https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization

How can we consume a Raw generic xml message? Any suggestions?.    Do we need to specify a schema for it? If yes, How?

You'd have to use Newtonsoft with the raw XML serializer options.

What is the model specification we need to define for using raw xml?  This will be used in the consumer contract
